# how to set zoom range for time ("%H:%M") in flot chart?

Tags: flot

i have to set min and max zoom range for time. for example 00:00 to 23:00.

```
xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                font: { color: "black"},
                timezone: "browser",
                timeformat :"%H:%M",
                labelWidth: 30,
                zoomRange: [0, 0]
}
```